# Configuring nginx settings .NET 8 Razor Application for AWS Toolkit Publish

Tags: c#, .net, nginx, razor, aws-toolkit

I am trying to publish a .NET 8 Razor page application to an Elastic beanstalk instance using AWS toolkit in visual studios.

I have been able to publish the application however I'm unsure how to properly configure the nginx settings and if it is possible to do this in a file in visual studios that gets copied over during aws toolkit publish. Or if I need to do this in the instance itself?